# JHipster/Microservices frontend development hot reload

Tags: docker-compose, microservices, jhipster, browser-sync

I have created a JHipster microservices application and want to do some frontend development on it. Launching the whole microservices stack in the ./docker-compose/ directory with `docker-compose up -d` works as expected. Registry shows all microservices, the gateway and an UAA instance with status 'up'. No exceptions thrown. Login to http://localhost:8080 works as expected.
Launching `yarn start` in the gateway project directory launches the development server via webpack and browsersync. Hot reload works as expected when pointing the browser at http://localhost:9000.

Now to my problem/question: logging into http://localhost:9000 as user/user doesn't work, as the account cannot be retrieved. The thrown exception is irrelevant because it just states that the account is null:

```
webpack-internal:///…fesm5/core.js:16064 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): 
TypeError: Cannot read property 'langKey' of null
TypeError: Cannot read property 'langKey' of null
  at LoginService.setPreferredLanguage (webpack-internal:///… 
login.service.ts:34)
  ....
```

But when I point the browser back to http://localhost:8080, I'm logged in as 'user'. Which means that the login on the backend worked.

Being new to docker and microservices, I'm suspecting that I'm conceptually missing something (networks/ports/etc..). Any ideas that could point to finding a solution?  Or what is the suggested setup/practices for developing the frontend in a JHipster/microservices configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There has been an error in the **webpack.dev.js** configuration file and because UAA was added later to the project, the UAA module was missing in the contexts to be proxies:

```
devServer: {
    contentBase: './build/www',
    proxy: [{
        context: [
            '/microservice1',
            '/microservice2',
            '/microserviceuaa',     /* !!! was missing !!! */
            /* jhipster-needle-add-entity-to-webpack - JHipster will add entity api paths here */
            '/api',
            '/management',
            '/swagger-resources',
            '/v2/api-docs',
            '/h2-console',
            '/auth'
        ],
        target: `http${options.tls ? 's' : ''}://127.0.0.1:8080`,
        secure: false,
        changeOrigin: options.tls,
        headers: { host: 'localhost:9000' }
    }],
```